Keep Ignore ownership on this volume for APFS partition on local disk
I need to make a local partition for DATA only on the same disk than the OS disk.
I search to keep the box "Ignore ownership on this volume" ticked,
But it's untick on every reboot.
I tried :

diskutil disableOwnership command (and reset volinfo.database)
Disable macOS Security on recovery
Create APFS Container
New APFS partition
chmod, chown, chgrp ...


The only thing that seems to work is to create an ExFAT partition,
But I'm not a big fan of this method.

It may be that Apple only allows this on external drives. You could create an exFAT partition and put a disk image on it, would that work for your purposes?

It's about ExFAT I'm not OK, If I must create an ExFAT partition, I can use it as is.
But I keep the idea, thks :)

Why a new partition, what's wrong with just a new volume? I'm intrigued to know what it is you're actually trying to achieve. You should be able to ignore ownership by just checking the box in Get Info, no command line involved, no need to disable SIP [which can prevent many regular structures from working properly].

@Tetsujin: You cannot on the internal drive regardless if in the boot partition or another partition. In my case, I have Ventura installed on the 256 GB internal drive and user accounts on a 512 GB Thunderbolt 3 external SSD. I have no problems doing this on the external drive.

@Tetsujin The problème is exactly here, I need to check this box at every login, at every boot and use the administrator password, I cannot come to every office at every shift to make this operation. ^^' That why I tried to disable the SIP to see if it's change anything.

@DavidAnderson You're right, but my company policies don't allow external drives on computers, otherwise I would have made this choice too.

I can't test easily for internal drive, sorry. The only boot drive i have that actually has other partitions on it, the Mac considers to be external because it's on a PCI card.

No problems @Tetsujin :)
Thanks for your Help,
The simplest way to solve this issue still to format this partition to ExFat,
I'm not a huge fan, but it'll work like this.

The simpliest way to solve this issue still to format this partition to ExFat,
I'm not a huge fan but it'll work like this.
If anyone have a better idea, feel free to share it :)
